# Ubuntu 13.04 random boot

Tags: boot, nvidia

Hi I've installed Ubuntu 13.04 and after installing Nvidia drivers I'm having real troubles getting into Ubuntu.

Randomly it crashes before booting into unity(login screen?) with random messages but mostly ending with something like this: `nvidia license module nvidia taints kernel`, and after that something like: `failsafe kill process` or so.

Sometimes it just ends up stuck and allows me to type stuff and if I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> it responds but doesn't restart only freezes with distorted flashing symbols and colours so I have to hard reset. At other times it just freezes until I reset pc.

Usually after 2-3 restarts it finally boots and everything works but I cannot log out(I'm able to restart or shut down but not log out) I had this problem with logging out when I was using Ubuntu as Wubi but now it's worse since it is Russian roulette if it even boots.

I need Nvidia drivers but since I tried 304, 310, 313 version and all cause the same trouble. Using Nvidia GT440.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you're booting off a SSD hard drive? I had similar problems on 12.10 with my new computer. Turned out that it was a bug that causes lightdm to sometimes start before the nvidia graphics driver had time to initialize on systems with really fast loading times :)
However it seems it's been fixed in 13.04 (at least for me)

My solution was to edit this file /etc/init/lightdm.conf
and before the "exec lightdm" line insert a new line with "sleep 1", so it looks like this:

```
sleep 1
exec lightdm
```

Otherwise, it kinda feels like were looking at a hardware problem here...

Comment: Well I too had a thought that lightdm tries to start before driver is initialized, don't remember exactly all those messages but there was something saying about links not ready and stuff like that not sure..
However noveau seems to be working and I also have win 8 dual boot and there are no problems with the graphics card at all so I don't know what's going on.. I'm gonna try adding the "sleep 1" before lightdm next time ubuntu decides to boot :D thanks.

Comment: No problem, please let us know if it works out! :)